# Wiped my keyboard with a damp cloth and now my macbook pro 2017 keyboard cannot type on the login screen

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, hardware, performance, macos

My macbook pro 2017 was working fine and I decided to wipe it with a damp cloth and now it wont work on the login screen. But I went to recovery mode terminal and all the keys work fine there. I must have turned on some setting that disabled my keyboard while wiping it. What could I have done wrong?

Comment: Was the MacBook Pro shutdown when you cleaned the keyboard?

Comment: no it wasn't so i'm assuming i just pressed some keys. this is so weird how this can happen. it was just a damp cloth to wipe off dust on the keyboard.

Comment: is something to do with filevault?

Comment: Can you login to safe mode? Have a look at: [Use safe mode to isolate issues with your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201262)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my issue it was due to a speck of dust that got stuck in the command key. This was the reason why it wouldn't type in the login box but in the terminal.

Comment: the command key was constantly pressed down due to the dust that got it stuck. I didn't realize until i started just randomly pressing all the buttons and realized that command wasn't pressing down and inspected further. After taking it out, they keyboard started working. It's the CRAZIEST thing ever. I couldn't use my computer for 2 days because of this! I thought it was a software issue and it was driving me NUTS! A usb keyboard didn't work neither!

Comment: You stated in the OP, "But I went to recovery mode terminal and all the keys work fine there" ... however, in **Terminal**, with the **⌘** _key_ stuck down, pressing any of these _keys_ **A C D E F H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Z** as well 10 or more non-alpha _keys_ will not type those alpha-characters pressed as they are _built-in keyboard shortcuts_ with the **⌘** _key_ stuck down. Therefore, the only _keys_ you could have pressed in **Terminal** and saw the characters typed,with the **⌘** _key_ stuck down, are **B G Y**. So something is not adding up with the statements you've made!

Comment: I don't remember anymore but terminal did work for whatever reason. It truly was an epic fix and problem that google would not have solved.

Comment: I have to update what I said in my other comment where I said, "Therefore, the only keys you could have pressed in **Terminal** and saw the characters typed,with the **⌘** _key_ stuck down, are **B G Y**." I made this statement out of what _keys_ were not _built-in keyboard shortcuts_ with the   **⌘** _key_ down, and having now just tested with the **⌘** _key_ down, no characters can be typed! So the bottom line is, statements you made in both the OP and your answer contradict.  There is no way with the  **⌘** _key_ stuck down that anything was typed in **Terminal** while in **Recovery Mode**.